# Voice controlled timer on macOS

Tags: macos, time

Siri can't set a timer on macOS, is there an app that can set up a timer using voice on macOS?

Comment: Siri is extensible, what makes you think Siri can’t work on a Mac?

Comment: It's not an inbuilt functionality at least. How would I extend it? I'm after an off-the shelf solution

Comment: Great follow on question. Catalyst and Xcode is how I do it currently on macOS. You’ll probably get someone answering “no - not easy” - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit

Comment: I'm a developer, but just wanted a simple tool - not a side project opportunity 

Thanks for an answer anyway!

Comment: I don’t know why -2 votes. Hang in there. I’m sure someone will have an answer at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that is good enough for my use case is [Firefox Voice](https://github.com/mozilla-extensions/firefox-voice):

> Firefox Voice is an experiment in a voice-controlled web user agent

It comes from Mozilla which I trust not to misuse my data and allows me to easily set a timer in [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com).